# VBScript Recordset Field Names and Length

Tags: sql, vbscript

Using VBScript, I create a recordset from a SQL query through and ADO connection object. I need to be able to write the field names and the largest field length to a text file, essentially as a two dimensional array, in the format of FieldName|FieldLength with a carriage return delimiter, example:

Matter Number|x(13)
Description|x(92)
Due Date|x(10)

Whilst I am able to loop through the Columns and write out the field names, I cannot solve the issue of Field Length. Code as follows:

```
Set objColNames = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(LF14,2,true)
For i=0 To LF06 -1
  objColNames.Write(Recordset.Fields(i).Name & "|x(" & Recordset.Fields(i).ActualSize & ")" & vbCrLf)
Next
```

in this instance it only writes the current selected Field Length.

Comment: Please define "current selected Field Length".

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner The recordset contains around 100 rows and I think it is returning the ActualSize property of either the first or last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more research and testing I solved the issue by creating a dictionary based on the recordset field (column) count, then iterating through each item and evaluating the length of each field:

Dim Connection
Dim Recordset

```
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Connection.Open LF08
Recordset.Open LF05,Connection

LF06=Recordset.Fields.Count

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objColNames = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(LF14,2,true)
For i=0 to LF06 -1
  d.Add i, 0
Next

Dim aTable1Values
aTable1Values=Recordset.GetRows()

Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(LF07,2,true)

Dim iRowLoop, iColLoop
For iRowLoop = 0 to UBound(aTable1Values, 2)
  For iColLoop = 0 to UBound(aTable1Values, 1)
    If d.item(iColLoop) < Len(aTable1Values(iColLoop, iRowLoop)) Then
      d.item(iColLoop) = Len(aTable1Values(iColLoop, iRowLoop))
    End If

    If IsNull(aTable1Values(iColLoop, iRowLoop)) Then
      objFileToWrite.Write("")
    Else
      objFileToWrite.Write(aTable1Values(iColLoop, iRowLoop))
    End If
    If iColLoop <> UBound(aTable1Values, 1) Then
      objFileToWrite.Write("|")
    End If
  next 'iColLoop
  objFileToWrite.Write(vbCrLf)
Next 'iRowLoop

For i=0 to LF06 -1
  d.item(i) = d.item(i) + 3
  objColNames.Write(Recordset.Fields(i).Name & "|x(" & d.item(i) & ")" & vbCrLf)
Next
```

I then have two text files, one with the field names and lengths, the other with the query results. Using this I can then create a two dimensional array in the CMS (VisualFiles) from the results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (I'm not certain I do)....

If you change your SQL statement you only need to return one record.

```
 Select Max(Len([Matter Number])) as [Matter Number], 
  Max(Len([Description])) As Description, Max(Len([Due Date])) As [Due Date] FROM TableName
```

This will return the maximum length of each field. Then construct your output from there.

Comment: This is something I had considered, although the method is dynamic, so the number of columns can vary and, whilst I can extract the column names to an array, the table name would be unknown, let alone the conditional clauses subjected within the query. Short of evaluating the sql passed into the method, I'm unsure how I would attain this.

Answer (score 0):

To get an extrema item (largest, smallest, ...) of a collection you need a loop over all elements that checks the current element's value against the known 'extrema so far':

```
>> a = Array(1, 3, 2)
>> x = a(0)
>> For i = 1 To UBound(a)
>>     If a(i) > x Then
>>        x = a(i)
>>     End If
>> Next
>> WScript.Echo x
>>
3
```

Comment: This is coherant with the sort of solution I anticipated, but I am not sure your offered solution provides enough clarity. Can you elaborate using the syntax references provided?

Comment: Especially as you 'anticipated' the principle demonstrated in my sample code you surely can adapt it to an outer loop over the recordset, an array of extremas (one element for each column), and an If check in an inner loop over the (current) fields.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate your response with provided sample code, I do not fully comprehend how the references provided relate directly to fields in a recordset.This is why I asked you to attempt to correlated syntactic example.